# How to fix "Timestamp expired" response from REST API when triggering an event

Tags: php, laravel, events, pusher

While broadcasting a Pusher event, I am getting below error:

```
(1/1) BroadcastException Timestamp expired: Given timestamp (2017-10-18T00:55:07Z) not within 600s of server time (2017-10-17T12:23:17Z) in PusherBroadcaster.php (line 106) at
  PusherBroadcaster->broadcast(array(object(PrivateChannel)), 'App\\Events\\TestEvent', array('message' => 'How are you')) in BroadcastEvent.php (line 48) at
  BroadcastEvent->handle(object(PusherBroadcaster)) at
  call_user_func_array(array(object(BroadcastEvent), 'handle'), array(object(PusherBroadcaster))) in BoundMethod.php (line 29) at
  BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}() in BoundMethod.php (line 87) at
  BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(object(Application), array(object(BroadcastEvent), 'handle'), object(Closure)) in BoundMethod.php (line 31) at
  BoundMethod::call(object(Application), array(object(BroadcastEvent), 'handle'), array(), null) in Container.php (line 539) at
  Container->call(array(object(BroadcastEvent), 'handle')) in Dispatcher.php (line 94) at
  Dispatcher->Illuminate\Bus\{closure}(object(BroadcastEvent)) in Pipeline.php (line 114) at
  Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(BroadcastEvent)) in Pipeline.php (line 102)
```

I am using windows.

This is the error message: `Timestamp expired: Given timestamp (2017-10-18T00:55:07Z) not within 600s of server time (2017-10-17T12:23:17Z)`.

I have configured my Pusher broadcasting correctly and triggered the event but then – nothing.

Here is a screenshot of the Laravel stack trace and the Pusher debug console.

[image]
[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What does your event creation/pushing code look like?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Vagrant / Homestead your system time can shift and become out of sync when your computer goes to sleep.

```
vagrant ssh
sudo apt install ntpdate
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
sudo timedatectl set-ntp on
sudo service ntp stop
sudo ntpd -gq
sudo service ntp start
```

Then

```
  cd /path/to/homestead
  vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
  vagrant halt
  vagrant up
```

I had the same issue and correcting my system time in this manner solved it for me.  The discussion here was helpful: 
https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/799

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error is pretty clear, the timestamp on the event (2017-10-18T00:55:07Z) further than 600s from the current server time (2017-10-17T12:23:17Z). So one of those is wrong. So, check the code is setting the timestamp correctly, and check the server time is correct.

Comment: how to set timestamp in laravel ..? how can I correct it.